# Holomorphic symplectic form on the moduli space of Higgs bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, smoothness, holomorphic-symplectic

I have the following problem: consider the moduli space $\mathcal{M}:=\mathcal{M}_X(n, 0)$ of semistable Higgs bundles of rank $n$ and degree $0$ on a compact Riemann surface $X$ of genus $g\geq2$. Can one characterise the smooth $\mathcal{M}^{sm}$ locus of $\mathcal{M}$? Moreover, do we know whether there exists a holomorphic symplectic 2-form on $\mathcal{M}^{sm}$? I know that this can be done on the open subset $\mathcal{M}^{stable}$ of $\mathcal{M}^{sm}$ of stable Higgs bundles, but I am not sure whether stable is equivalent to smooth (i.e. I think there are strictly semistable Higgs bundles which are smooth points of $\mathcal{M}$). I know the following paper

http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/49/2/219.extract

of Biswas and Ramanan, where, at Theorem 4.3, they seem to give a positive answer to my question. On the other hand, in that theorem $\mathcal{M}$ is considered as a formal scheme (I am not even sure about what they mean by this), so I do not know whether that result actually gives an answer to my question.

Comment: Weil-Petersson metric is not smooth, since they use fiberwise hermitian metric and such metric are not smooth

Comment: We take such 2-forms you are saying as current and not form.

Comment: @HHH are you referring to the paper of Biswas and Schumacher? I took a look at it and they seem to define the Weil-Petersson metric onnly on the moduli space of stable Higgs bundles. Do you have another paper in mind? Thanks for your reply anyway.

Comment: Yes,  Biswas and Schumacher,Y.T. Siu, R. Kaufmann,  S Wolpert , Matei Toma

Comment: @HHH, can you tell me the specific paper you have in mind? All the ones that I know seem either to consider only stable vector bundles, but, in the case I am looking at, I am taking semistable vector bundles. Thanks!

Comment: In semi-stable case fiberwise hermitian metrics which is semi-positive gives foliation on null direction and we don't know how to solve Donaldson's flow as Monge-Ampere foliation on such direction.